# Trying to connect to a mysql database, getting exception saying Must specify port number after:

Tags: java, mysql

I’m trying to connect to a MySQL database on my website from java.

Currently I’m getting a exception that says

> Must specify port number after:”

I Google stack overflow and found the default MySQL port is 3306.
But I can't find any information about how I add it to my url, which now looks like

```
jdbc:mysql://http://www.findmeontheweb.biz/database name"+
     “user=findmeon_bitcoin&password=password
```

code:

```
  try {

          // this will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          // setup the connection with the DB.
          Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://http:                  //www.findmeontheweb.biz//findmeon_bitcoin//"+ "user=findmeon_bitcoin&password=oreo8157");


 } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception...." );
    }
```

Comment: Why is there a giant wad of spaces in the JDBC URL? Also, is that really your correct MySQL URL? And your user name and password?

Comment: remove that space...

Comment: I now have your database credentials. I don't need to purchase one.. :)

Comment: Change your password asap!

Comment: Why do you have an http url inside your jdbc url? That doesn't make sense. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html for the syntax of a mysql URL.

Comment: I would never ever post my question with the correct username and password. You have given it all buddy. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Hope the space in your code was only a copy/paste error here

2) You need to remove the http in the mysql uri

```
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://http:                  //www.findmeontheweb.biz//findmeon_bitcoin//"+ "user=findmeon_bitcoin&password=oreo8157");
```

will be

```
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://findmeontheweb.biz/findmeon_bitcoin/"+ "user=findmeon_bitcoin&password=oreo8157");
```

And just in case you are running it on a custom port, you can specify port by

```
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://findmeontheweb.biz:3306/findmeon_bitcoin/"+ "user=findmeon_bitcoin&password=oreo8157");
```

replace 3306 with your custom port.

Also I hope that is not your real username and password!